# PHP: preg_replace for replacing $foo

Tags: php

How to replace this,

Here is the text :

```
$foo = '/var/www';
$foo2='/var/www';
```

Here is the php

```
function showBBcodes($text) {

// BBcode array
$find = array(
'/\*(.*?)\*/',
'/\`(.*?)\`/',
'/\"(.*?)\"/',
'/echo/',
'/if(.*?)/',
'/\$(\W+)/i',
'/<\?php/',
'/function/',
'/\?>/'
);

// HTML tags to replace BBcode
$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<span style="color:red;">`$1`</span>',
'<span style="color:red;">"$1"</span>',
'<span style="color:#239A1B;">echo</span>',
'<span style="color:#1B5C9A;">if</span>$1',
'<span style="color:#1B5C9A;">$$1</span>',
'<span style="color:#111CC7;">&lt;?php</span>',
'<span style="color:#669933;">function</span>',
'<span style="color:#111CC7;">?&gt;</span>'
);

// Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
```

I want to replace `$foo` with `<span style="color:#1B5C9A;">$foo</span>`

I read the php manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

But I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'/\$(\W+)/i',` that should be `\w` for word character. You said "non word character" which is the exact opposite of what you wanted. Also the `i` modifier after the closing slash is superflous: both lower and upper case letters are equally in `\w`.

Comment: heu, its work dude, thx. by the way. do you have link what that symbol like (.*?) mean ? thx